# Are "Desktop", "Documents", etc. folders localized on filesystem level on Windows?

Tags: windows, tkinter, localization, savefiledialog

An user of my program can select a new filename in "Documents" directory using "Save As" dialog (Python's `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename`), but they can't complete the operation, because system gives following error:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/48772756/62299342-10f25100-b475-11e9-9033-f29a6cc549f5.png]

It looks like this problem has to do with French used as Windows language.

The user says that they can save into parent directory (ie. into home directory), but not under "Documents" and "Desktop".

Any ideas how this situation can occur and how to solve it?

On which level does the special folder localization happen? Is "Desktop" directory translated in filesystem?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example/snippet of your code? The `asksaveasfilename` should work without a glitch.

Comment: @FrainBr33z3, It should be simple `asksaveasfilename(..., initialdir=...)`. I have English system, so I don't know for sure, which arguments can reproduce this. In my system I haven't been able to repro this neither with existing nor non-existing `initialdir`.